# Scraping IDs from three different divs and presenting them as an array?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have something like this:

```
<div id="sub_div">
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">2204830011</span>     
      <div class="node">1571827122</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>    
      <div class="node">...</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>      
    </span>
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">...</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>     
    </span>
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">...</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>     
      <div class="node">...</span>     
   </span>
```

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
  def self.parse_nodes

    id       = @data.at_css("#n_info #clipnode").text unless @data.at_css("#n_info #clipnode").nil?
    name     = @data.at_css("#n_info .node_name").text unless @data.at_css("#n_info .node_name").nil?
    parent   = @data.at_css(".bc a").text unless @data.at_css(".bc a").nil?

    children_array = []
    children = @data.css('#sub_div')
    children.css('.subl').each do | child |
      child_id = child.css('.node').text[/[\d,]+/].to_i
      children_array ||= []
      children_array << child_id
    end 

    nodes_hash = "id: #{id}, name: #{name}, parent: #{parent}, children: #{children_array}"
    nodes_hash
  end
```

And I'm getting something like this:

```
[220483001115718271223064201115857511158575013463330111571879115709231157103512258019011157197311570657115706941,

220483001115718271223064201115857511158575013463330111571879115709231157103512258019011157197311570657115706941,
 220483001115718271223064201115857511158575013463330111571879115709231157103512258019011157197311570657115706941]
```

I have no idea why the code is presenting all the `.node` three times. But anyway, the thing I want to do is to scrap the content inside `.node` of each of the `.subl` divs and present them as an array:

```
[2204830011, 1571827122, 3064201115, 8575111585, 7501346333,
0111571879, 1157092311, 5710351225, 8019011157, 1973115706,
57115706941]
```

Live site: http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/Apparel/1036682

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
children = @data.css('#sub_div')
children_array = children.css('.subl .node').map { |node| node.text.to_i }
```

OR

```
children = @data.css('#sub_div')
children_array = children.css('.subl .node').map(&:text).map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I don't know how I didn't see that. But I still get results like this: `[22048300111571827122306420111585751115857501, 3463330111571879115709231157103512258019011, 157197311570657115706941]` how can I do it to get the result I mentioned above?

Comment: @alexchenco, Using the code and the url, I get `[103670024025540111040666, 10406641574363115743161, 104065822270300111040660, 0]`. Maybe you're using different url?

Comment: Oh, yeah, but that's not important. All those pages have the same structure. I just want the content of all the `.node` divs to be listed in an array. In your case: `[1036700, 2402554011, 1040666, 1040664, and so on...]`

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I will wait for the votes and then check the one with the most.

Comment: _Downvoter: How can I improve the answer?_ Edit your answer, so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @alexchenco,  _I will wait for the votes and then check the one with the most._  Based on my experience, most voters have no idea what they are voting for--they tend to vote for their friends regardless of the content of the posts.  They have no idea what issues were raised in the question or how the answers address the issues/ overlook the issues/don't understand the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces the following output:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html =<<END_OF_HTML
<div id="sub_div">
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">2204830011</div>
      <div class="node">1571827122</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>    
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>      
    </span>

    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
    </span>
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">1</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
   </span>
</div>
END_OF_HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

children_array = []
children = doc.css('#sub_div')

children.css('.subl').each do | child |
  child_id = child.css('.node').text[/[\d,]+/].to_i
  children_array ||= []
  children_array << child_id
end 

p children_array

--output:--
[22048300111571827122, 0, 1]
```

The reason you are getting numbers concatenated together is because when you write:

```
child.css('.node')
```

...you get a NodeSet that contains all the divs with class="node".  The text() method extracts all the text nodes from a NodeSet and concatenates all the text together with no spaces:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = "<div><span>hello</span><span>world</span></div>"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

spans = doc.css("span")
puts spans.text

--output:--
helloworld
```

So when you write:

```
child.css('.node').text
```

...you get many numbers concatenated together into one string.

Here is what you can do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html =<<END_OF_HTML
<div id="sub_div">
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">2204830011</div>
      <div class="node">1571827122</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>    
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>      
    </span>

    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
    </span>
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">3333333</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
   </span>
</div>
END_OF_HTML


doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
results = []

doc.css("#sub_div span.subl div.node").each do |div|
  if num = div.text[/[\d,]+/] 
    results << num.to_i
  end
end

p results

--output:--
[2204830011, 1571827122, 3333333]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach :-

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eotl
<div id="sub_div">
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">2204830011</div>
      <div class="node">1571827122</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>    
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>      
    </span>

    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
    </span>
    <span class="subl">
      <div class="node">3333333</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
      <div class="node">...</div>     
   </span>
</div>
   eotl

doc.xpath("//div[@id='sub_div']//div[@class='node'][boolean(number()) or . = 0]").map{|n| n.text.to_i}
# => [2204830011, 1571827122, 3333333]
```

Comment: What if there are other divs contained in sub_div that have numbers for text that do not have class="node"?

Comment: Okay, now add the condition for <span class="subl">.

Comment: @7stud Then I would add this - `[@class='node']` . Very simple!! :) I told you earlier also,I answered as I am seeing in my post. Never impose anything from my mind. :)

Comment: _What all other answers handled in their ruby code,I handled it in xpath level._ In fact, you just ignored some conditions. There could be divs with class="node" outside `<span class="subl">`.  What does the `.` do in the number() function? What if some of the numbers are 0?

Comment: @7stud I could write also `text()`, but here `.` do will do the same job. Because `.` is the context node on which `string()` function is applied,which is its text value. `number()` will give you `NaN` for all non-number text. And if you apply the `boolean()` on `NaN`,you would get `false` back. That's the trick I used. Did OP mention he not interested on `0` number.. ? So I didn't care this.. :)

Comment: Babai, those are all rhetorical questions.  The dot does nothing because number() already uses the current context. And if one of the nodes has the number 0 in it, your xpath will skip it.  So, no, what the other answers handled in the ruby code, you did NOT handle in your xpath.

Comment: @7stud Humm! Good point(*And if one of the nodes has the number 0 in it, your xpath will skip it*) I handled.. it now.. :) Thanks for helping me to fix that. `number(text())` can be optimized to `number(.)`, that can also be optimized to `number()`. The last one I was not aware of,probably I never did dig till that point,because I was happy till `number(.)`. But from now I will use `number()`. :)\